# How do you safely bottle or "can" bbq meat drippings?

Tags: meat, canning

I want to bottle (and store) about 16 oz of barbcue drippings I captured from cooking brisket.

Do I have to use the "pressure canning" method to can the drippings, or can I just bottle it using the boiling water bath method?

I would prefer the latter. But either way, do I need to add citric acid to make it safe? And if so, how do I know how much to use?

Comment: Why not just freeze them?

Comment: And you should note how long you plan to save it for, that will make a difference in how you will likely want to treat the drippings.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ- In my case I can things because the freezer is full of meat.

Answer (score 3):

Because meat stock is low-acid you're going to need to use a pressure canner. Follow the pressure and times indicated in a reliable guide such as this one from the [Montana State Extension](http://msuextension.org/publications/HomeHealthandFamily/MT200905HR.pdf)

You won't need to add acid to make it safe.(edit)